# Could I specify the order of part of the section for gcc/ld

Tags: gcc, ld

I am developing a test code on X86/Linux. And I hope to use the linker_lists.h header from u-boot. The purpose of the header is explained in https://gitlab.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/doc/README.commands

However, the section order is wrong without a link script

```
.u_boot_list_2_0_2_rc13m_stop
                0x00000000006de798       0x10
 .u_boot_list_2_0_2_rc13m_stop
                0x00000000006de798       0x10 obj/embedded_studio_project/unittest/hw_sim_ut.o
                0x00000000006de798                _u_boot_list_2_0_2_rc13m_stop

.u_boot_list_2_0_1
                0x00000000006de7a8        0x0
 .u_boot_list_2_0_1
                0x00000000006de7a8        0x0 obj/embedded_studio_project/unittest/ict1200_sw_test.o
                0x00000000006de7a8                ict1200TestSuite::TearDown()::start

.u_boot_list_2_0_3
                0x00000000006de7a8        0x0
 .u_boot_list_2_0_3
                0x00000000006de7a8        0x0 obj/embedded_studio_project/unittest/ict1200_sw_test.o
                0x00000000006de7a8                ict1200TestSuite::TearDown()::end
```

The problem is the section u_boot_list_2_0_2_rc13m_stop is out of the u_boot_list_2_0_1 and u_boot_list_2_0_3.
For the linker list to work correctly, we have to use some link script containing

```
    .u_boot_list : {
        KEEP(*(SORT(.u_boot_list*)));
    }
```

My question is could I specify only the order of these u_boot_list sections? And let the linker decide the other placement as usual?

Answer (score 0):

Several days passed and no answer. So I post my work around here, in case someone met the same problem.
There is a link option: --verbose. It will dump the default link script. So I simply add the wanted section sort part to the link script. Then add the "-T link_script" option to override the default one.